# Ubuntu SDK asks to install Xephyr on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: 15.10, ubuntu-sdk

While trying to build and run a project, ubuntu-sdk says:

> Starting /usr/bin/autopilot3-sandbox-run... E: Xephyr executable not
>   found. Please install Xephyr /usr/bin/autopilot3-sandbox-run exited
>   with code 1

I can't find that package on the repositories.
Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install the Xephyr X server for the emulator.

> sudo apt-get install xserver-xephyr

Comment: Another good one!  **;-)**